# SVN - how does removing a bin folder cause the src folder to be removed instead?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

There was a bin folder in version control with a bunch of .class files and other junk that should not be versioned.  Could someone please explain to me how the following commit:

```
529  svn rm --force bin/
530  svn ci -m "Bin should not be under version control."
```

Leads to the following:

```
Revision 249
Author:     ndunn
Date:   Mon Jul 26 14:52:14 2010 UTC (62 minutes, 34 seconds ago)
Log Message:    

Bin should not be under version control.

trunk/projname/src/     deleted
```

I went back through the svn logs as someone reminded me that this had happened before - sure enough, one two separate occasions developers had attempted to remove the bin folder and instead the src folder completely disappeared.

Any idea what the heck could be going on?  This is an Android project that's under version control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7ddd4044f775b8f4) solves the mystery

> My problem is that when I start working into the project, the /bin
>   folder is generated by the SDK and a copy of the .svn folder from /src
>   is copied into /bin/.svn, which breaks by subversion structure.

So anyone using Eclipse with Android had better be prepared to have any changes made to the bin folder reflected in src... wow.

Picture solution:
[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/552e113d8ad854e128dae56cf0a4a775.png](http://grab.by/grabs/552e113d8ad854e128dae56cf0a4a775.png)

Comment: Great find - very interesting.  And scary.

Comment: You could delete the .svn folder from /bin

Comment: Adding the *.svn exclusion pattern causes the entire project to be rebuilt, meaning the .svn folders go away.

Comment: `.svn/` appears to be the case for Windows

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to set `svn:ignore` property on parent (of `src` and `bin`) with value `bin` to prevent committing bin folder.
BTW: In our team 2 persons also deleted `src` while trying to delete `bin` - it seems it is Eclipse related problem...

Comment: why would you ignore the src folder?

Comment: @Oritm I mean to ignore only bin folder. I have just fixed my answer.