# Lost source code android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got a problem with my Eclipse. I clean project and restart my Eclipse. But when openning project, all my resource , java file was lost. Name of file still appear but source code had been lost and all file were 0kb.
I don't know how to sovle this problem. Please help me?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OnjDEwk.png

Comment: hope you made a backup

Comment: Poor!  I did not backup! :(

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but this came to mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336576/svn-how-does-removing-a-bin-folder-cause-the-src-folder-to-be-removed-instead